# passing propTypes values setup in Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

new to react native, i am doing this tutorial: http://rationalappdev.com/movie-tickets-booking-app-with-react-native/ but there is a line of code that i don' t understand: `const { movie, movie: { title, genre, poster }, onOpen } = this.props;`

basically, the Movie component, call the MoviePoster component by passing to it a 3 values propTypes:

```
render() {
    return (
    <View>
        <ScrollView>
        { movies.map((movie, index) => <MoviePoster
            movie={movie}
            onOpen={this.openMovie}
            key={index}
        />)}
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
    );
}
```

and here is MoviePoster component:

```
    export default class MoviePoster extends Component {
  // Component prop types
  static propTypes = {
    // Movie object with title, genre, and poster
    movie: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    // Called when user taps on a poster
    onOpen: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }
  render() {
    const { movie, movie: { title, genre, poster }, onOpen } = this.props;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={() => onOpen(movie)}>
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
          <Image source={{ uri: poster }} style={styles.image} />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={1}>{title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.genre} numberOfLines={1}>{genre}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

i don' t understand is this line: `const { movie, movie: { title, genre, poster }, onOpen } = this.props;`

1. is it like a kind of mapping the props into the constant ? How can it be possible as the Movie component pass 3 datas ( an object, a function and a key) and in const we have different types, how can it be match ?
2. can we call directly in the MoviePoster component : this.props.movie.title, this.props.onOpen() or this.props.key for example ? if so, what is the need for the const ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is called nested object destructuring. He is simply creating constants from the passed props and mapping them, to type `{title}` instead of `{this.props.movie.title}`.

You can definitely use the longer version, this is just a shorthand.

Check this link for more info:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Check the "Nested object and array destructuring" section.

Comment: Thanks, i have a close look on the article